# Parsing JSON, data turns Nil in API Service Using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, alamofire, swift4.2

I was about to get data from API, when I tried to print the response from the API, it printed successfully, and when I tried to print the data from an Object, it also printed successfully, but when I checked the variable **attendees** in my `APIService`, the value is always **nil**,that's why when passing the value in UI it also turns into **nil**. How can I get the data from JSON to reflect to **attendess** in Api Service. I am too puzzled regarding this. Please help me. Thank you.

**getParticipant Function in API Service**

```
func getParticipants(passcode: String,
                     participantType: ParticipantType,
                     successBlock: @escaping (Attendees?) -> Void,
                     failureBlock: @escaping (Error) -> Void)
{
    let attendeesURL = URL(string: "\(GET_PARTICIPANTS_URL)/\(passcode)/\(participantType)")

    Alamofire.request(attendeesURL!, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

        if let error = response.error
        {
            failureBlock(error)
            return
        }

        if let attendeeJSON = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String, Any>],
            let attendeeObj = attendeeJSON.first {
            print(attendeeObj)
            let attendees = Attendees.init(JSON: attendeeObj)
            successBlock(attendees)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**attendees in UI which should accept data also turns into nil because attendees in APIService is nil**

```
var passcode = ""
var attendees = [Attendees]()

 @IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //readvalues

    passcode = passcodeLabel.text!


    //check if empty

    if(passcode.isEmpty)
    {
        _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Ooops!", subTitle: "Please input valid event code.")
    } else {
        getParticipants()
    }

}

//GET PARTICIPANTS FUNCTION

func getParticipants() {

   // var participantType: ParticipantType!



    let api = APIService(APIKey: passcode)

    api.getParticipants(passcode: passcode, participantType: .all, successBlock: { (attendees) in


        if let attendeesArray = attendees {

            self.attendees = [attendeesArray]
            do {
            DispatchQueue.main.async{

                _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Message", subTitle: "Details:\(self.attendees)")

                return
            }

        }
        }

    }) { (error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async{

            _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Network Error", subTitle: "Network Error:\(error)")

            return
        }
    }
```

**Sample JSON**

```
[
{
    "event_name": "Laugh Trip",
    "event_participants": [
        {
            "participant_id": "6f1e7fd5-6da9-4d5b-bc91-4771aeaa5235",
            "employee_number": "",
            "last_name": "name",
            "first_name": "name",
            "middle_name": "",
            "display_name": "name, name ",
            "department_name": "IT",
            "position_name": "Application Developer",
            "registered_flag": true,
            "registered_datetime": "2018-07-16T14:51:57.813",
            "registration_type": 1,
            "delete_flag": false,
            "manual_reg_flag": false,
            "out_flag": true,
            "out_datetime": "2018-07-16T14:54:00.000",
            "classification": 1,
            "others": ""
        },
```

Comment: It seems that the root object is a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian how can I debug it? Thank you

Comment: Apology, for that I think I over edited it, I have codes there. Thank you

Comment: Great. I'd suggest losing the screen snapshots and all of this unrelated code, and show us (a) the `Attendees` definition and its `init(JSON:)` method; and (b) rather than printing `response`, can you show us a representative example of what the actual JSON looks like? There are subtle issues that get lost unless we can see the raw JSON. E.g. when you `print` the `response`, we can't differentiate between numeric types and strings that contain numeric types (which is a common source of problems). Only by looking at raw JSON can we diagnose this.

Comment: I am using postman to check raw JSON. That will do?

Comment: I edited my question and I included the JSON. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your **Attendees** model's data type is mismatched

- You should check every parameter's datatype of response and compare with your created **Attendees** datatype

I hope this will work because of I faced this problem and solved it

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I am totally new in swift. Do you have any references? Thank you.

Comment: can you show me what are you doing in **Attendees**?

Comment: I edited my question, I added the **Attendees** class, **JSON** and **getParticipant Function** in View Controller. Thank you

Comment: Do to set nil, 
If datatype is Bool set default value is False, 
If datatype is String set default value is empty string "", 
If datatype is Int set default value is 0 

And try it

Comment: which part of the code will i place it? Apology, I am really confuse

Comment: can you give me your API response than I can copy it?  I will give you proper a solution later

Comment: It is on the **getParticipant Function in API Service** part of my attached code above. Thank you so much

Comment: Please put full response here not image

Comment: Yes, I do have codes included in my question not just image. Please see **getParticipants Function** or can send you? I cant comment the codes in here. Thank you

Comment: The API response codes are located at **getParticipants Function APIService** above :)

Comment: I edited my question and I included the JSON. Thank you.